# Size of PCA decorrelation matrix?

Tags: pca, random-variable, covariance-matrix, svd, eigenvalues

I have a $P\times K$ matrix $\mathbf X$ with $K$ random vectors as columns (with the respective means subtracted from each entry). My goal is to decorrelate the columns of $\mathbf X$ via PCA to obtain the transformed matrix $\mathbf Y$ of the same size as $\mathbf X$.

I proceed as follows: I form the $P \times P$ covariance matrix $\mathbf C=\frac{1}{K}E\big[\mathbf X \mathbf X^\top\big]$. Let the eigendecomposition of the covariance matrix be $\mathbf \Sigma=\mathbf U\mathbf \Lambda \mathbf U^T$ where $\mathbf U$ contains the eigenvectors and $\mathbf \Lambda = \text{diag}\{\lambda_i,\cdots,\lambda_{P}\}$ is the eigenvalue matrix of $\mathbf 
 \Sigma$. The eigenvalues correspond to the variances. To decorrelate the columns of $\mathbf X$, we multiply this matrix on the left by $\mathbf 
 \Lambda^{-1/2} \mathbf U^T$: 
$$\mathbf Y = \mathbf \Lambda^{-1/2} \mathbf U^T \mathbf X,$$
 so that the transformed data $\mathbf Y$ will have an identity covariance matrix.

In the above process, it is not clear to me how the sizes stack up. Because $\mathbf Y$ is of size $P \times K$, I must have $\mathbf \Lambda$ of size $P \times P$. On the other hand, the eigenvalues correspond to variances of the random vectors in question. I have $K$ random vectors in the matrix $\mathbf X$. Therefore, I should get $\mathbf \Lambda$ of size $K \times K$.

What am I missing here?

**Edit after [@whuber](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/919/whuber)'s remarks:**
If I form a $K \times K$ covariance matrix, then the dimension of $\mathbf \Lambda^{-1/2} \mathbf U^T$ is $K \times K$. I can not, therefore, multiply $\mathbf \Lambda^{-1/2} \mathbf U^T$ to the $P \times K$ matrix $\mathbf X$.

**Second edit after some more research:** 
The eigenvalues of $\mathbf X \mathbf X^\top$ and $\mathbf X^\top \mathbf X$ are same (see [this link](https://www.cs.colostate.edu/~cs510/yr2013/Progress/L11_RossPCA.pdf)); in the bigger matrix, rest of the eigenvalues are simply zero. Therefore, it doesn't matter which way I form the covariance matrix. I am not sure if the variances (which are eigenvalues themselves) would be same in both cases.

-ryan

Comment: $C$ is not the covariance matrix!  The covariance matrix is found by forming the $K\times K$ matrix $X^\prime X$ ("E" is meaningless here: it applies to random variables but not to data) and dividing by $P$.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the clarification. I meant to say I have formed a matrix of random vectors that I want to simultaneously decorrelate. I have modified my question now. If I form a $K \times K$ covariance matrix, then the dimension of $\mathbf \Lambda^{-1/2} \mathbf U^T$ is $K \times K$. I can not, therefore, multiply $\mathbf \Lambda^{-1/2} \mathbf U^T$ to the $P \times K$ matrix $\mathbf X$.

Comment: "On the other hand, the eigenvalues correspond to variances of the random vectors in question" -- No. I don't even understand what this could mean. What is a variance of one vector?